# Setting Unique Body Classes and IDs in Orchard

Tags: .net, orchardcms

Is there a way to set unique body classes and IDs per page in Orchard? I would like to be able to control these on the 'edit page' section.

For example, the home page would have the body id of 'home', the about page would have a body ID of 'about' etc...

And -- if there were subpages under the about page, those pages would have a body ID of 'about' and a body class unique to the subpage.

I would like to be able to set these IDs and classes on the 'edit page' section for each page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Classy feature in Vandelay.Industries (available from the gallery). It's a part that you can add to a content type in order to be able to set classes and ids, and also add scripts.