# Orchard - add class or id to the body using fields

Tags: class, field, orchardcms, document-body

My questions is - **how do I add a class or id to the body tag using a text field within Orchard?**

So if I enter the word "product" in the text field then the result should be `<body class="product">`. I want to use this method instead of creating alternate layout templates as every page has the same layout but I need a different class for each page to reference a different colour scheme I have setup for each page in my CSS.

I have added a text field with the name Area to the Title ContentType in the backend. My problem is now how to get the value of the field to be put into the body in the Document.cshtml.

I have read [Setting Unique Body Classes and IDs in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575941/setting-unique-body-classes-and-ids-in-orchard) and [Using Alternatives for Document.cshtml in Orchard CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877821/using-alternatives-for-document-cshtml-in-orchard-cms) but I still can't get it to work! The second one seems like what I want to do but so far I have been unable to acheive it.

Any answer would be very appreciated?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 1):

I am so frustrated that there is no readily available solution found in the net about this. Since I am more comfortable coding in jquery & js...

Here's my solution: Assuming you have jquery loaded...

```
@using(Script.Foot()) {
<script type ="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var count = url.match(new RegExp("/", 'g'));
    var urlsplit = url.split("/");
    var page_class = urlsplit[count.length];

   alert(page_class);
    $('body').addClass(page_class);
});
//]]>
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use the Classy feature from Vandelay.Industries.

Comment: Hi Bertrand, Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I think I'm going to need a different method as this doesn't appear to work for Projection Pages i.e. the Class, ID, script fields don't appear in the backend. Also I haven't been able to get the classname to render on the body tag. I have read [http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/259938](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/259938) and works for the content but just get an empty space when I try to apply it to body!? Any ideas would be very welcome? Thanks

Comment: May be a bug. Are you saying you added the part to the content type and it still doesn't appear in the item editor? If so, please file a bug. In any case, the techniques in the module should at least help you create your own solution to your particular problem, even if it doesn't work directly from Classy.